# MVC Routing picking up Area controllers at root

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having difficulties with my controllers that are in an Area answering requests on routes that aren't for the area. So I have a setup like this (Extra stuff cut):

```
/Areas/Security/Controllers/MembersController.cs
/Areas/Security/SecurityAreaRegistration.cs
/Controllers/HomeController.cs
```

I have my area for security defined:

```
namespace MyApp.Web.Areas.Security
{
    public class SecurityAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Security";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Security_default",
                "Security/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And my global routing rules:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*robotstxt}", new { robotstxt = @"(.*/)?robots.txt(/.*)?" });
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Web.Controllers" }
        );
```

In my global asax I'm doing quite a few things but the relevant part is that I call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` then I call the routing function that does the above.

But my problem is that requests for "/Members/" are hitting my Members controller using my "Default" route... even though the controller's not in the namespace I specified. Then when it tries to run it can't find it's Views cause they're defined in the Area and it's trying to find them in the overall Views folders. I tried making the route namespace `"Weird.Namespace.With.No.Content"` and it STILL hits the Members controller - I can't find any way to make it not use that controller. How do I make it not answer requests that aren't in it's area?

Comment: Is `MembersController` defined in `Security` area? In what namespace it is defined?

Comment: The namespaces all match the folders, `MyApp.Web.Areas.Security.Controllers` namespace, `MembersController` class (All occurances of `MyApp` are replaced with the name of our actual app - I've anonymized slightly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up finding a solution by changing the Route to:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Web.Controllers" }
    ).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

For some reason with that unset it seemed to always find my Controllers no matter where they were and totally disregard my namespaces - even from other referenced assemblies. Looking through the ILSpy of `DefaultControllerFactory` it looks like `GetControllerType` eventually falls back to searching absolutely every controller if it doesn't find the controller in the namespaces you asked for...

This flag seems to be set automatically on the Routes I made in a specific area, but not on the ones I made globally. When I set it on the global ones they began behaving how I had originally expected. I have no idea why you'd ever want to turn this on...

Answer (score 1):

You should register the namespace on your area as well.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Security_default",
            "Security/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new []{ "MyApp.Web.Areas.Security.Controllers"},
        );
    }
```

And then make sure all your controllers are in their appropriate namespaces.

Comment: All controllers definitely have the appropriate namespaces (`MyApp.Web.Areas.Security.Controllers` class `MembersController`, and `MyApp.Web.Controllers` class `HomeController`).

I tried your suggestion, even though I wasn't sure how a namespace on the route URL starting with "Security/" could impact a request for "/Members", and it didn't have any impact. I can even set that namespace to a namespace that's not real and the area keeps answering.

As far as I can tell the namespaces supplied aren't doing anything...

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling register all areas after registering your main route?

This is the default snippet from the MVC template (note how area regisration goes first)

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Comment: Yes, areas registered before routes. I know area comes first, but I tried it both ways anyway. I also tried it without even registering the area it still happened. the answer above did resolve it, though I'd still love any logical reason why it happens (I've found why in code by decompiling MVC, but I can't come up with a reasonable reason why it should :))

Comment: Routes are greedy and not re-entrant. So if one of the routes match it will win and then run. If your conventional route matched, it will run whatever controller name and action names match the tokens it found. If your areas routes don't match for any reason this could happen. Another thought - Are your area controllers being hit? If so what is the scenario where you hit non area controllers?

Comment: I'm aware routes are greedy - that doesn't relate to the problem. As I listed out I'm getting answers when I expect NO answer, it's not that 1 route is super-ceding another, it's that a route is using Controller classes that are in a namespace I didn't want associated to that Route (Notably Area controllers being hit by my Default binding) even though I set the namespace property on the route (Which as per my answer above seems to only be a "first place to look" and not any kind of restriction).

Comment: Your description is fairly accurate, but what I don't understand is why these controllers are not handled by the area route they are in. They should match and routing should have stopped and never get to the more general route.

Comment: Because as I said the request was for "/Members/" which doesn't match the binding of the Area. It instead matches the "Default" route, but the default route shouldn't have had a "Members" controller available to service the request so I'd expect a 404, instead it went and used the one defined in an entirely different namespace intended for the Area (And other stuff like the View lookups went haywire too as a result). Requests for "/Security/Members/" worked fine.

Comment: Now I get it. This seems by design, and your code is the right way to deal with it.

Comment: Yep - just a very bizare design. Without knowing it did that it resulted in some nasty unexpected issues when it exposed controller classes that were inside framework DLLs that we never even considered a user might be able to hit without us routing it. Was pretty lucky that there wasn't any security holes due to this.

Comment: Can you make these controllers abstract?

Comment: Yeah - many are, but others were set up with the design that you didn't have to have an app-specific implementation & you just set up a Route to them to get that feature running (Mostly ones that are interacted with via JavaScript - adding the route hooks up all the JSON callbacks). It's working fine with the above code, it just strikes me as crazy - I can't imagine any scenario where I'd want the default behaviour.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52315/discussion-between-yishai-galatzer-and-fyjham)